# Free subgroup of a quotient

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $F$ be a free group on $x,y,z$. Fix $n>1$ (I am ready to assume that $n$ is large enough). Let $\mathcal{W}$ be the set of *cyclically reduced* words $w$ in $F$ where the letter $z$ appears at least once (i.e., such that $w\notin \langle x,y \rangle$).

Let $N$ be the normal subgroup of $F$ generated by $\{w^n:w\in\mathcal{W}\}$.

> Is the image of $\langle x,y \rangle$ mod $N$ a free group on two generators?

Remark: if $\mathcal{W}$ is replaced by a single element in it, this follows from the Freiheitssatz.

Comment: You definitely need more restrictions, otherwise $z^n$ and $(z^ny)^n$ lie in $N$, thus $y^n$ lies in it as well.

Comment: Am I correct that w can be any word not in $\langle x,y\rangle$ and is $n$ fixed or not fixed?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I want fixed $n > 1$ (you can take it as large as you want). And $w$ is indeed any word involving $z$.

Comment: @Pablo, I'm still confused.  Is $N$ the normal closure of $w^n$? Or the normal closure of the set of $w^n$ for *all* such words $w$?  If the former then, as David Jackson says, this is the Freitheitssatz (and works for any $n$).  If not, you need to look into the techniques used to study Burnside-type groups.  One modern expert who I'm sure could answer your question is Remi Coulon.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "generated by the word $w^n$" rather than "generated by the words $w^n$"?

Comment: @HJRW I meant the latter: $N$ is the normal closure of the set of $w^n$ for all such words $w$ with fixed $n > 1$. And thanks for the advice.

Comment: @DerekHolt I think that I meant what I wrote (in plural form). That is, I mod out by all $n$-th powers of reduced words which involve $z$. Thanks for asking for this clarification.

Comment: @Pablo so, Ilya's comment answers your question

Comment: @Ycor I am ashamed to say that I fail to see why.

Comment: $z$ and $z^ny$ are cyclically reduced words involving $z$, so in $F/N$ $z^n=1$ and $(z^ny)^n=1$, hence $y^n=1$. So $y$ is torsion in $F/N$.

Comment: @YCor you are right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As observed by Ilya Bogdavov in a comment, the answer is obviously no since the quotient $F/N$ has exponent $n$.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I am greatly misunderstanding the question (I assume both $w$ and $n$ are fixed), the answer to the question is YES and this follows from Der [Freitheitssatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiheitssatz) (W. Magnus, 1930).

If the question assumes that $N$ is generated by the word**s**, $w^n$, rather than the word, $w^n$, we can assume that for (large) $n_1,n_2$ which are relatively prime, that both $w^{n_1}$ and $w^{n_2}$ are in $N$.  Then $w\in N$, so $F/N$ is a one-relator group and $z$ occurs in $w$ by hypothesis.

Obviously, I was interpreting the question as having $N$ generated by 
the words $w^n$ for some fixed cyclically reduced word, $w$, and and many values for $n$, rather than having $N$ generated by $w^n$ for all cyclically reduced words $w$ which are not in $\langle x,y \rangle$.

Comment: Right, but I want $n$ fixed and $w$ varying.

Comment: @Pablo my mistake, I shouldn't have edited; now I've essentially reverted to David's previous version of his answer